# Windows phone app player not working when submitted to the store

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, media-player

I have windows universal 8.1 app with two players. When I deploy locally using app deployment application or through visual studio it is working fine but when I submit app to the store, one player fails to work.
I am using microsoft player framework with this hls plugin https://phonesm.codeplex.com/
The player seems to load since I know player media opened event has triggered but player control is missing and there is no video or audio.
When try to play video content nothing happens but when I try to play audio only content I get audio but there is still no visible player control (player visibility is set to visible ofc).
The question is, how is it possible that the same package acts different whether deployed locally or acquired from store?

Comment: Does it work when build in release mode and deployed to the device? Btw if you need HLS playback, this is a much better choice https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/MicrosoftHLSSDK

Comment: It works when built in release mode too. Eventually I made it work and I'm not really sure how. i use UserControls as Pages and when I created clone of control with player and used it instead of the original one.it didn't work but then I uncommented original one while keeping clone as valid one for displaying it worked.
There is nothing I changed about player but it became fixed. I wish I had a normal explanation.
Thanks for the link, I will surely explore it.